# Truncated rice binarization method

Tags: binary, hevc

Based on **HEVC** standard, decimal quantized coefficients are binarized through different methods, e.g. Truncated Unary, Truncated Rice (*k*-th order), Exp-Golomb, etc.

Considering the Truncated Rice method, I cannot understand the role of *cmax* parameter that completely changes the output. I have understood how the algorithm works, but I do not find any reference about that parameter. It seems that the Truncated Rice does not depend by *cmax*, however different outputs return for associated different values.

Comparing the two attached images, you can note the different binarized outputs based on *cmax*. Can you provide any reference that explains how the algorithm works based on *cmax*?

[image: First example]

[image: Second example]

Answer (score 0):

Could you add references to these screen shots, so we can read and understand the notation?

PS: I assume you have already read [Transform Coefficient Coding in HEVC](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6324418) paper, but you still need more detailed information.